# Photo Collage in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I want to make a html(css/js) website where I can drag photos from my computer with drag&drop and then (based on a chosen layout) to make a collage (drag&drop also) with 2 or more pictures. My question is: How can I do that? 
I know how to use the draggable option or how to drag photos from one point to another in my website. Unfortunately i do not have any idea of how can i upload pictures from my computer that i want to use in my future collage or how to create those layouts (in which i put the photos).

If you know a website with these kinds of tutorials it would be good also (I coundn't find anything helpful).
Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it with a JS library!

recently I used http://www.dropzonejs.com/ for drag and drop files uploading. 
it's working fine and has some good configurations to set.

but for saving files to the server you might need some PHP as well.